# I downvoted an answer and commented to explain the downvote, then received 3 random downvotes on old answers I posted

Tags: discussion

I provided some feedback on an answer and downvoted it. Very soon after I received 3 downvotes for random answers I posted (which generally had upvotes) within the same minute and the answer I downvoted was removed.

Is behaviour like this captured and monitored? Whilst I cannot say for sure that a person did this maliciously, it seems likely in this case. I know it's only points so I don't mind but I am interested in what is done "behind the scenes" to stop this kind of behaviour.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think those are gonna stick. 3 downvotes AFAICT, is not enough to trigger the reversal script.

Comment: Context: [this is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17528783/1348195) , the comment was: "-1 Whilst this is very informative, it is nothing to do with the OP's question. The OP didn't ask how to connect to a database and get information out. He wants the data in a set format. Points about using PDO or mysqli should be in a comment." . For what it's worth I think your comment was perfectly fine and was not rude at all.

Comment: I agree with possible duplicate. If it's not removed after ~48h you can flag one of your question for moderator attention, but with your rep... is -6 rep even worth your time and nerves? You'll get more from one good answer than you lost thanks to this guy, and it'll be way faster than fighting for reversal. And he will get caught or he will go away if he's that kind of person.

Comment: As a general rule i'd advise against putting -1 in the comments, it links the downvote with the commenter and basically asked to be revenge downvoted. The comment could live alone without the -1

Comment: @Mołot - I didn't know the terminology so apologies for the duplicate, feel free to close it. I don't mind about the points, they can be easily earned again, I was just interested in how it's dealt with as I suspected I am not the only one who could potentially suffer from these.

Comment: @RichardTingle - I thought it was advised to say why you down voted so users can improve upon the answer.

Comment: @webnoob I can't close, I'm next to nobody here, just wanted to provide some insight to you.

Comment: Indeed, say **why**. Just not that it was **you** who downvoted. It'll be 90% obvious that its you, but that lingering doubt will prevent most revenge

Comment: @RichardTingle it's sometimes safer to word a comment like *"If you want to avoid downvotes, it would be better to edit your question, blah blah..."*

Comment: @webnoob In short, anything that isn't persistent won't be dealt with. So in your case, those 3 downvotes will probably stick. From what I've seen, it usually takes 4 or 5 to trigger the (downvote reversal) script. But it doesn't take rocket science to figure that out, so people can usually get away with a small number of revenge downvotes as long as they don't persist. But in any case, 3 downvotes on 3 different posts probably won't do too much damage.

Comment: Good points guys, will keep it mind in future. Thanks. Feel free to close the question as a dupe (not that you need my permission :P) as I have clearly posted a dupe.

Comment: @RichardTingle I often -1 to 'come clean' and explain my rational. I agree with what you're saying though - I always add 'please don't take personal offense in the vote, I'm thankful for your input and know you're just trying to help, thanks.'

Comment: That question title sounds much better, thanks for the edit. Think my typing is following my mixed up mind today, I blame hay-fever :)

Comment: Ironic I lost 6 points on SO but gained 45 here asking about it :) I can live with that trade :P

Comment: The important bit is the explaining your rationale, @Ben - if you can leave voting out entirely, that only helps to emphasize the valuable bits.